# Restrict the user to access one folder only and deny all other folder in D: drive

Tags: permissions, users

I am running windows server 2008.
I have a user to which I need to set permission so that he can access only one particular folder and deny access to all other folder.How can i set the permission.

Comment: This question is being closed because we're not going to do your job for you.

Comment: for example jail is your username `icacls  d:\ /deny jail:f` then `icacls  d:\yourfolder /grant jail:f`

Comment: And use powershell instead of cmd.cmd won't access the path.

Answer (score 5):

> On NTFS volumes, you can set security permissions on files and folders. These permissions grant or deny access to the files and folders. You can view security permissions for files and folders by completing the following steps:
>
> 1. In Windows Explorer, right-click the file or folder you want to work with.
> 2. From the pop-up menu, select Properties, and then in the Properties dialog box click the Security tab.
> 3. In the Name list box, select the user, contact, computer, or group whose permissions you want to view. If the permissions are dimmed, it means the permissions are inherited from a parent object.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

By default users have read permissions on files and folders and subfiles and -folders inherit those. What you normally want to do is to remove those from the D: drive and only grant permissions to specific groups like "Department A", "Department B", … to your folders. THen put your users into the respective groups. That way they will  only have access to the folders you grant them access.

Denying access is something that is not considered a good way of configuring permissions. You may want to take the time and reorganize your permissions.

Comment: we have many users created in the server.In that one user(w2wconnect) needs to access only one folder which is in D: drive and restrict all other folders to him(w2wconnect).All other users can have full access to all drives and folders.

Comment: I want the permission settings in detail

Comment: @Kiran: No one here is going to do your work for you. The thing you can expect is that someone tries to explain the principles to you and it's your task to understand them and apply to your specific problem. If you expect more, you are wrong here.

Comment: Also consider marking this as an answer, because it is the answer to your question. That would help other people who are looking for an answer here and also be appreciative towards me and the time I took to help you.